# Proper htaccess rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to force an old URL to go to the new url and my code seems to have no effect

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^index2\.php?page=shop\.product_details&\.tabs\.tpl&product=310&category=71&Itemid=2$

RewriteRule .*  /hunting/back-packs/multi-packs/black-2.5-pack.html [R=301,L]
```

my old url is

```
www.mywebsite.com/index2.php?page=shop.product_details&.tabs.tpl&product=310&category=71&Itemid=2
```

and my new one is

```
www.mywebsite.com/hunting/back-packs/multi-packs/black-2.5-pack.html
```

My code does not break anything but does not work either

Thanks in advance

Comment: sorry, thanks. I have removed the escape chars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you want redirect (301 Permanent Redirect) so the URL will change in browser. This will work for this URL **ONLY** `/index2.php?page=shop.product_details&.tabs.tpl&product=310&category=71&Itemid=2`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =page=shop.product_details&.tabs.tpl&product=310&category=71&Itemid=2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^index2\.php$ http://www.mywebsite.com/hunting/back-packs/multi-packs/black-2.5-pack.html [R=301,L]
```

If you want **internal** redirect (**rewrite**), then use these lines:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =page=shop.product_details&.tabs.tpl&product=310&category=71&Itemid=2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^index2\.php$ /hunting/back-packs/multi-packs/black-2.5-pack.html [L]
```

**PLEASE NOTE:**

1. You need to put these lines in a proper order (**order of rules matters**) otherwise (if you put it at the end) some another rule will rewrite it to a different URL.
2. This needs to be placed in .htaccess file in website root folder. For any other location you may need to modify it a bit.

Comment: Worked perfectly!  Thanks LazyOne

Comment: The redirect works with a minor oddity.  The redirect takes the user to :    http://www.mywebsite.com/hunting/back-packs/multi-packs/black-2.5-pack.html?page=shop.product_details&.tabs.tpl&product=310&category=71&Itemid=2    Which is a concatenation of the two urls.  Was this expected or is there a way to strip that off.

Comment: Are you talking about 301 redirect (first rule)? In any case -- it should not -- try adding `?` at the end of URL (`.../black-2.5-pack.html?`). If still nothing then I have to look into it again.

Comment: Yes, first rule.  Thanks, adding the ? to the end worked.  Not sure I understand why, but thanks again

Comment: Adding `?` at the end should discard existing query string. Glad it worked well (as some people saying that "sometimes" it does not work well for them).